# Is there any way to delete photos with the Instagram API?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, instagram, asp.net-web-api

I tried doing a DELETE request to /media/{id} in the API console on their website, after authenticating with my own account and finding a photo id, but it said 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED. Plus there are obviously built in requests for deleting comments, likes, etc.

Is there a workaround for this, or is it hopeless?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this? If you could update with your findings it would greatly help others following in your footsteps

Comment: @weesplodge unfortunately, no. I believe it's impossible after all I've tried, and after seeing how incredibly restricted the Facebook API is as well it further confirms (since FB owns Instagram) my belief that it can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API endpoint for delete media and there is not plan to add in near future

Reference : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media#updating

Thanks

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: Agreed with @Filnor. The link is broken already.